# Zend_Db_Table_Row error create new row

Tags: zend-framework, orm, zend-db-table

i have a table

```
--
-- Table structure for table `pages`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `text` longtext,
  `enabled` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

form

```
class Admin_Form_Page extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setDisableLoadDefaultDecorators(true)
            ->setElementDecorators(array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Label',
                'Errors',
                array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p'))
            ));

        $this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            'Form'
        ));

        // Add Elements

        $this->addElement('hidden', 'id', array('decorators' => array('ViewHelper')));

        $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
            'label' => 'Название страницы',
            'required' => true
        ));

        $this->addElement('text', 'title', array(
            'label' => 'Заголовок страницы',
        ));

        $this->addElement('textarea', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Текст страницы'
        ));

        $this->addElement('checkbox', 'enabled', array(
            'label' => 'Страницы включена'
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'save', array(
            'label' => 'Сохранить',
            'decorators' => array(
                'ViewHelper',
                array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p'))
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

and model

```
class Default_Model_Pages extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name = 'pages';

    protected $_cols = array('id', 'name', 'title', 'text', 'enabled');

    protected $_primary = 'id';

    public function getPagesList($enabled = true)
    {
        $sql = $this->select();
        if (true === $enabled) $sql->where('enabled = 1');
        return $this->fetchAll($sql)->toArray();
    }
}
```

then i wont create new page with Zend_Db_Table_Row

```
...
$pageData = $pageForm->getValues();
$id = (!empty($pageData['id'])) ? (int) $pageData['id'] : null;

$pageRow = (null === $id)
    ? $pageTable->createRow($pageData)
    : $pageTable->fetchRow($pageTable->select()->where('id = ?', $id))->setFromArray($pageData);

if ($pageRow->save()) {
    $this->view->content = '<p class="info">Save Ok</p>';
} else {
    $this->view->content = '<p class="error">Save error</p>';
}
```

i have error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception' with message 'Cannot refresh row as parent is missing' in /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php on line 764 Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception: Cannot refresh row as parent is missing in /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php on line 764 Call Stack: 0.0002 657224 1. {main}() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/public/index.php:0 0.0509 8922848 2. Zend_Application->run() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/public/index.php:16 0.0509 8922848 3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Application.php:366 0.0509 8922984 4. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:97
```

if i unset $pageData['id']

```
$pageData = $pageForm->getValues();
$id = (!empty($pageData['id'])) ? (int) $pageData['id'] : null;
unset($pageData['id']);
```

i have error

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php on line 745 Call Stack: 0.0002 657224 1. {main}() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/public/index.php:0 0.0448 8922848 2. Zend_Application->run() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/public/index.php:16 0.0448 8922848 3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Application.php:366 0.0449 8922984 4. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:97 0.0467 9404896 5. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:954 0.0497 9895472 6. Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:295 0.0497 9903880 7. Admin_IndexController->pagesAction() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php:513 0.0643 13499456 8. Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->save() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/application/modules/admin/controllers/IndexController.php:29 0.0643 13499456 9. Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->_doInsert() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php:438 0.0656 13504264 10. Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->_refresh() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php:497 0.0656 13504264 11. Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->_getWhereQuery() /home/ergallm/www/gps.local/library/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php:759
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: if delete in table protected $_primary = 'id' all work good, but why it's not work with primary key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is due to the fact that you assign `$_cols` variable yourself. When you do this, the Zend_Db_Table is not properly initialized. According to the [Zend Framework reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) to specify columns you should overwrite describeTable() method:

> _setupMetadata() sets the schema if the table name contains the pattern
>   "schema.table"; calls describeTable()
>   to get metadata information; defaults
>   the $_cols array to the columns
>   reported by describeTable(). *By
>   overriding this method, you can
>   specify the columns*.

EDIT: Some more insight.

Specifically your `Default_Model_Pages` is not properly initialized, because the `_setupMetadata()` of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract is not executed. Normally it is executed when `_primary` or `_cols` variables are not set. Because, in your `Default_Model_Pages` you manually set these two variables, the `_setupMetadata` is not run. This is also the reason why everything worked when you removed `protected $_primary = 'id';` from your class. In that case `$_primary` was not set, and subsequently,  `_setupMetadata()` was called within  `_setupPrimaryKey()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the cols via:

```
$table = new YourTable();
$cols = $table->info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::COLS);
```

or just use below in your model file:

```
$this->info(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::COLS)
```